# What does error code -1073741819 mean when caused by ng build?

Tags: angular, msbuild, angular-cli, teamcity

**Background:**
A project I am working on is built in Angular 7, is based on the Visual Studio 2017 Angular project template, is managed using TeamCity, *and* more specifically is built on a Windows 10 build agent.  We've been able to build this project for the last few months with few issues.

Last Friday, however, we started seeing a strange error when the project was building:

`error MSB3073: The command "npm run build -- --prod" exited with code -1073741819.`

Now, before anyone gets distracted by the funny command (we did!), `npm run build -- --prod` is what Visual Studio 2017 projects are configured to run to build Angular projects by default.  If you run that command in your Visual Studio Terminal Window, what you'll see it evaluates down to `ng build "--prod"` - specifically, in your Web project, you'll find a line like `<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build -- --prod" />`

I looked up [the Angular CLI's build command](https://angular.io/cli/build), but could find no list of error codes anywhere, so I have no idea what that error code is in the context of `ng build`.

The only resources I have been able to find on error code `-1073741819`, are related to the Windows UAC settings, specifically [that one may need to mess with sound settings or edit the registry](https://appuals.com/file-system-error-1073741819-on-windows-10/)...if you've just upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10, back from 2015.

**Questions:**
1. In the context of `ng build`, what does error code `-1073741819` mean?
2. Is there a list of error codes that the `ng build` command can emit anywhere?  That might help me answer the first question, but would also be good for general reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promoting Tom Blodget's [correct comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57856292/what-does-error-code-1073741819-mean-when-caused-by-ng-build#comment102150432_57856528) to an answer, -1073741819 is `0xC0000005` which is `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

Answer (score 0):

> error MSB3073: The command "npm run build -- --prod" exited with code -1073741819.

The error actually means that `npm` exited with that code.

*npm* will forward the exit code from the scripts it executes, but since it doesn't look like there is any output generated. I would just assume that `npm` is failing before it even starts the scripts. You could verify this by changing what the *"build"* script is doing to something useless like `""`.

With all that said...

> 1073741819

Is a Windows File System error code.

It's most likely that the hard drive is the point of failure here. Since your builds worked a week ago and have now broken. It's safe to assume you need to replace that HD as soon as you can.

Comment: File system? Maybe. -1073741819 is 0xC0000005, which is [FACILITY_WINDOWS | FACILITY_WIN32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/structure-of-com-error-codes) | [ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-)—very generic.

Comment: @TomBlodget How do your code parts come about? 0xC0000005 is actually something like `(1 << 30) | MAKE_HRESULT(SEVERITY_ERROR, FACILITY_NULL, ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)`, where (1 << 30) is "R - reserved portion of the facility code, corresponds to NT's second severity bit.", playing a role in regard to severity of system error codes.