# Failed to execute goal: com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.27:npm

Tags: java, build, frontend, npm-install, maven-plugin

Someone have problem with failure to build an maven project when the fail is about this dependecie:com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.27:npm ?

[build Failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ia3dp.png)

I tried to build a maven project, but it always fails on this error. I already changed the maven version and deleted the m2 folder to start over, but the error persists. Does anyone have any tips, or has been through this and managed to resolve?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It would be better to copy-paste the output of the terminal in the post, instead of a screenshot. This is better searchable and helpful for responders.

Answer (score 0):

npm install returned with an error code. It looks like a Windows File system error code. [So it's most likely that the hard drive is the point of failure here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57856292/what-does-error-code-1073741819-mean-when-caused-by-ng-build#:%7E:text=The%20error%20actually%20means%20that,there%20is%20any%20output%20generated.).

`-1073741819` is `0xC0000005` which is `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.